# How to only load Axios API call once every session

Tags: vue.js

I have an HTML site that also uses vue for a couple of functions, I use axios to fetch API Data. Now my problem is, whenever a user goes back to the index after browsing other pages, it has to fetch the API Data again, which makes my site load slow.

```
First site load --> Fetch API Data
Go to other pages --> 
Goes back to main menu --> Fetch API Data Again
```

What i want is for the API to only fetch once, and whenever the user visits other pages and goes back to the main menu, it won't have to load again. Is there any methods to accomplish this?

Comment: May be with caching in Vue https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/caching.html#page-level-caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a session cookie after you fetch your data and check if it exists before you try to fetch data.